# Retrieving values of objects in a parse database

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, undefined

So I'm trying to pull the name of the creator, just for testing purposes, from the session object. The creator object is a pointer but it keeps coming up as undefined however? Any clue why?

```
function joinLobby(){
  var ses = Parse.Object.extend("Session");
    var query = new Parse.Query(ses);
    query.equalTo("Name", document.getElementById("lobby").value);
    query.find({
    success: function(results) {
      console.log("Successfully retrieved " + results.length );
      // Do something with the returned Parse.Object values
      session = results[0];
      addPlayer(session,player);
      console.log("session joined: "+session.get("Name"));
      console.log("The creator is: "+session.get("Creator").get("Name")); // coming up as undefined
    },
    error: function(error) {
      alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
    }
  });  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the query does not load the object pointed by the pointer. To do that you need to add this extra line and then run your query.

`query.include("Creator");`

Comment: You are querying the Session class where the records do NOT store a Creator object but simply store a Pointer object. The pointer is simply pointing to a Creator object in another class. In order for you to get the object that is referenced by the pointer (or to dereference the pointer as they say), you need to `fetch` that object separately. However the `include` method lets you do this simultaneously while running the query which is quite convenient.